# Workaround for using a private struct

Tags: c++, class, struct, mesh

I am using an engine for my console application. This engine can not be changed. The engine contains a class called Mesh. There's a public method in this class `findBoundaryLoops()` which I'm using in my class (which is not part of the engine) but I have to pass a parameter to this method which type `VertexLoop` is defined as a private attribute. I'm not sure that I explain it well, so there's a representation of the code:

Mesh.h:

```
class Mesh final
{
private:
    ...
    struct VertexNode
    {
        Edge connectingEdgeWithNext;
        Vertex vertex;
        VertexNode* prev;
        VertexNode* next;

        float angle;
    };

    struct VertexLoop
    {
        VertexNode* firstNode;
        uint32_t nodeCount;
        template<typename Callable>
        void forEachNode(Callable&& f)
        {
            VertexNode* n = firstNode;
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nodeCount; ++i, n = n->next)
            {
                f(n);
            }
        }
    };
    ...

public:
    ...
    void findBoundaryLoops(memory::MemoryArena& arena, vector<VertexLoop>& loops) const;
    ...
};
```

I have to use the `findBoundaryLoops()` method, but the `VertexLoop` struct is private. Is there a workaround or something to solve this problem?

Comment: Impossible to guess from just that tiny bit of code. Is the engine publicly available? (Also, this looks a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: Why did you make `VertexLoop` private in the first place? Also note that it is easily accessible. Its the parameter type of a public method, hence can be accessed. It is not `private` in the sense you think it is.

Comment: Hence the question is unclear. What is "this problem" you actually need to get solved? Why is it not a solution to declare the struct in the public section?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number as I said, this Mesh class is from an engine which cannot be change. I am just using this engine in this case from source code but it could be a dll or something. So that's because to declare the struct in the public section is not working for me

Comment: @molbdnilo No, the engine is not publicly available, that's why I tried to insert as minimal code as I can here

Comment: @molbdnilo But I think it's not so important, it can be a general problem. There's a class which declare a struct as a private attribute. Also there's a public method which is using this struct as a parameter and you want to call this method somewhere else outside of this class of course. How can you do this? Is this even possible somehow? I just don't see why it isn't a problem and why is it a solution

Comment: If the engine is "reasonable", there should be some other way of accomplishing whatever it is you want to accomplish by calling this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer has two parts. Below I will show you how to access the type declared in the private section. But I think the important point, and thats why I put it first, is to realize that you should not need the below solution. Anybody can access `VertexLoop`. The name is private the type not. There was no point to declare it in the private section in the first place. If the type appears on the signature of a public method you can as well put it in the public section.

If this is library code or generated code, then either you misunderstand how to use it, or it  can be considered broken.

---

Simpler example:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    private:
        struct bar{};
    public:
        void f(std::vector<bar>&){}
};
```

Now we write a trait that given a member function of `foo` with a single `vector` parameter tells us the `value_type` of that vector. Then we instantiate it with a pointer to `foo::f` to get an alias to `bar`:

```
template <typename X> 
struct bar_type;

template <typename T> struct bar_type< void(foo::*)(std::vector<T>&)> { using type = T; };

using public_bar = bar_type<decltype(&foo::f)>::type;
```

Using it:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<public_bar> v;
    foo f;
    f.f(v);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/es86a5E1G)

Maybe worth to note that this is by no means comparable to "dirty hacks" by which one can access private members of a class (yes they do exist). This is not a hack, it is perfectly fine partial specialization of a trait to get the parameter type of a public method.

---

**TL;DR** Just don't do it. Move `VertexLoop` to the public section.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it works well! You're right, I also have brainf*ck from this code, but I can't touch it. Maybe a request or something should be a good option as you said before